# Koa.js + Next.js с чего начать?

Tags: reactjs, koa.js, nextjs

Решил переписать свое SPA на Next.js для SSR, но не могу понять с чего начать и на что в первую очередь обратить внимание.

К примеру раньше у меня был сервер:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const config = require('config');
const fs = require('fs');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const path = require('path');

require('./handlers/static').init(app);
require('./handlers/bodyParser').init(app);

const routerIndex = new Router({});

routerIndex.get('*', async function(ctx) {
   ctx.type = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
   ctx.body = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./public/index.html'))
});

app.use(routerIndex.routes());

app.listen(3030, () => {console.log(`App is running on port :3030`)});
```

И всё, т.е я отдаю весь SPA и дальше он на клиенте рендерится.

Как теперь нужно настраивать сервер, что бы он мог рендерить первый запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### настройка

**базовая** настройка *Nextjs* сводится к установке и создания файлов(по аналогии с `index`) в директории `pages`.

### с чего начать

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next#quick-start

> npx create-next-app

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages

### TypeScript

есть поддержка TS.
если переименовать файлы страниц в `*.tsx` и стартануть - *Nextjs* в консоле выведет сообщение, что нужно установить ещё пару пакетов, следуем инструкции, стартуем повторно, и всё работает.